# Writing a bash loop with < in html

Tags: html

I am trying to write the following piece of bash code on an HTML page:

```
for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
```

For this purpose, I am doing it in `<pre><code> </pre></code>`.

However, what I am getting is that everything between  appears, is not shown on the actual web page.

How can I introduce that piece of code to the HTML page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap `code` inside `pre`.
2. You'll need to escape the `<` in `i<len` as `&gt;`.

```html
For purposes of demonstration, here is some Bash code:
<code><pre>for ((i=0; i&lt;len; i++)); do</pre></code>
Fun!
```